# How from Columns separated dataset, to a comma separated one?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, dataset, user-defined-functions

i need to separate the columns of my dataset into comma separated how con I do this? I need a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

@VBasic2008 here is what i get in the middle of the sheet: the first and second row are my tries with your function CONCAT. While i need something like the rightest part of the image.... like 6,40,45,52. Not all the values merged..

[image]

So i did it using CONCAT function but i had to manually compute that for each column i show how for the ones that eventually will need help (note i used ; instead of , beacause my excel seems not working with ,)

[image]

and this is finally the final output

[image]

Ok but what if I have a dataset of 1000 columns? This process need to be much much quicker than this. This is not optimized.

Comment: Do you mean you have an Excel spreadsheet in which your data are separated into columns and you want to convert it into comma separated values? If this is your intention, you can just save it as .csv file format. You can do so by going to File --> Save As --> Choose File Format as any CSV, i.e. CSV UTF-8 (.csv). Then you should get what you want.

Comment: I've tried this one, setting csv separated by comma file, but when I open the file it looks like the same..

Comment: Excel tries to guess the data structure and turns the comma separated values into columns through the file extension. If you don't want it turns data into columns, all you need is to rename the file extension from .csv to .txt for example. Then open the tile with Excel then you will get what you want for sure.

Comment: What version of excel are you on? `Textjoin` does this

Comment: i have the 2016 one

Comment: What columns are you trying to turn into comma separated values? You should have the function mentioned in my solution. I can provide a VBA solution if you let me know what columns

Comment: @Veasna You're right, thank you for your precious help. I renamed the csv file, with .txt. opened and copied into excel. But when i open the file it's always separated in "columns". While what i'm seeking are all the values in the first column, separated by a comma. Nice advise btw

Comment: @urdearboy just checked and i can't find that.. Do i need more recent version?

Comment: It's a madhouse. I think in newer versions of Excel there already exists a CONCAT Function, so if you're trying to use my function, rename it to e.g. **CONC** and replace 'CONCAT = xdString' with **CONC = xdString**. Then use the function like I suggested **=CONC(A1:G1,",")** i.e. first the range and then  the separator (,).

Comment: @Carlo I think you didn't rename the file correctly. If you don't specifically see the file extension, you can't rename it. In Windows, you need to view the file extension, then rename it when you see it. On Mac, it normally asks you whether you want to keep the original extension or use the new one. I hope this help. You don't actually need to write any codes or functions to achieve what you want. It is practically simple. If you have renamed it correctly, just open the file with Excel application by File --> Open, not the other editors like Notepad. Just that you will get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written several comments on your question which may be hard to follow. So I decided to make a full solution which actually a trick.

Note that Microsoft Excel tries to guess the data structure of the file content if the file is suffixed with `.csv` (extension). For that reason, whenever you open a `.csv` file, you get your data in columns instead of `a single columns` with `comma separated values`.

In order to achieve what you want, first, save your data as in the comma separated values (`.csv`) file format.

Then change your file extension from `.csv` to, i.e. `.txt` (text file) for example:
if your file name is "data.csv", change it to "data.txt". Please make sure you see the file extension as `csv` before you change it because in some case you don't see the file extension; therefore when you rename it, it remains a `csv` file.

Note: If you don't see file extension, if you are on Microsoft Windows, follow this [link](https://www.howtohaven.com/system/show-file-extensions-in-windows-explorer.shtml).

Once you rename the file into txt file format, you can then open it in your Excel application by going to `File -> Open ->` then browse the `txt` file.

There you go and get what you one.

You don't need to code or use any functions to achieve that although you can choose to do so if you wish as it is also a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a formula solution

`TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, Range)`

where `Range` is the column span of expected values

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub CSV()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim LR As Long, xRow As Range
LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xRow In ws.Range("A1:A" & LR)
        xRow.Offset(0, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(", ", True, xRow.Resize(1, 6))
    Next xRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is already separated by commas, so you just have to rename it to a `.csv` file.

in Windows Explorer, go to the ribbon and go to the 'view' tab and enable 'File Name Extensions'.
Navigate to your file, right click and rename it to THEFILENAME.csv instead of THEFILENAME.xlsx

Now when you open this up in excel, it should have the grid.

Comment: I need a file that looks like the one in the image i've posted, the one I have has columns not commas

Answer (score 0):

What is the extension of the file? .xls, .txt or .csv?

If it is in .xls then you can simply open the file in Excel and then use the File->save as menu and then selecting the Comma Separated from the file type drop down.

If file has .csv extension and you are trying to open it in Excel then you will see columns even the file has commas in it. To verify that if the file is comma separated then simply open with notepad or other text editors to see the comma separated values.

If there is any other separator like colon : or other and want to replace with comma then simply use the find and replace option in notepad.

Comment: my original file is an .xlsx I transformed it in a .csv file but I'm always visualizing my dataset in columns. How can i do this? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

## CONCAT Excel UDF

I wrote this a while ago.
In VBE add a module and copy the following code to it.

### The Code

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:        Concatenates the values of cells of a specified range.
'                 Read only. String.
' Syntax:         CONCAT(Range, Separator, Row0Column1)
' Inputs:
'   Range         A valid range in any open workbook. Required.
'   Separator     A string to be used as a separator between the values.
'                 Default is the space character. Optional.
'   Row0Column1   If 0 it concatenates by row, if 1 then by column.
'                 Default is 0. Optional.
' Returns:        A string containing all the values of the specified range.
'*******************************************************************************
Function CONCAT(ByVal Range As Range, Optional Separator As String = _
    " ", Optional Row0Column1 As Long = 0) As String

'***************************************
  ' Variables
  Dim xdRowStart As Long, xdRowEnd As Long, xdRowCounter As Long
  Dim xdColumnStart As Long, xdColumnEnd As Long, _
      xdColumnCounter As Long
  Dim xdSep As String, xdString As String, xdCheckEmptyString As String
  Dim xdWS As Worksheet

'***************************************
  ' Values
  xdString = ""
  xdSep = Separator
  Set xdWS = Range.Worksheet
  xdRowStart = Range.Row
  xdRowEnd = xdRowStart + Range.Rows.count - 1
  xdColumnStart = Range.Column
  xdColumnEnd = xdColumnStart + Range.Columns.count - 1

'***************************************
  ' Determine concatenated direction: by row or by column
  Select Case Row0Column1
    Case 0
      GoTo ConcatenateByRow
    Case 1
      GoTo ConcatenateByColumn
    Case Else
      MsgBox "Row0Column1:" & vbCr _
        & "Ommit or use 0 for Concatenating by Row." & vbCr _
        & "Use 1 for Concatenating by Column."
      GoTo ConcatenateFinal
  End Select

'***************************************
  ' Concatenate by Row:
ConcatenateByRow:
  For xdRowCounter = xdRowStart To xdRowEnd
    For xdColumnCounter = xdColumnStart To xdColumnEnd
      If xdString = "" Then 'xdString is empty; all cells were empty so far
        xdCheckEmptyString = xdWS.Cells(xdRowCounter, xdColumnCounter)
        If xdCheckEmptyString <> "" Then 'Cell is not empty
          xdString = xdCheckEmptyString
        End If
       Else 'xdString is not empty
        xdCheckEmptyString = xdWS.Cells(xdRowCounter, xdColumnCounter)
        If xdCheckEmptyString <> "" Then 'Cell is not empty
          xdString = xdString & xdSep & xdCheckEmptyString
        End If
      End If
    Next xdColumnCounter
  Next xdRowCounter
  GoTo ConcatenateFinal

'***************************************
  ' Concatenate by Column:
ConcatenateByColumn:
  For xdColumnCounter = xdColumnStart To xdColumnEnd
    For xdRowCounter = xdRowStart To xdRowEnd
      If xdString = "" Then 'xdString is empty; all cells were empty so far
        xdCheckEmptyString = xdWS.Cells(xdRowCounter, xdColumnCounter)
        If xdCheckEmptyString <> "" Then 'Cell is not empty
          xdString = xdCheckEmptyString
        End If
       Else 'xdString is not empty
         xdCheckEmptyString = xdWS.Cells(xdRowCounter, xdColumnCounter)
         If xdCheckEmptyString <> "" Then 'Cell is not empty
           xdString = xdString & xdSep & xdCheckEmptyString
         End If
      End If
    Next xdRowCounter
  Next xdColumnCounter
  GoTo ConcatenateFinal

'***************************************
ConcatenateFinal:
  CONCAT = xdString
End Function
'*******************************************************************************
```

### Usage in Excel

`=CONCAT($A1:$G1,",")` and copy down:

```
=CONCAT($A2:$G2,",")
```

Comment: I've tried this one, but it gives me back all the values of the columns merged, while i need to have the same structure of the columns but separated with a comma, so i can use this dataset in programs like R. I've updated my post to let you see what I have using CONCAT